# self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES acting inconsistent

Tags: iphone, button, hide, navigationcontroller, navigationitem

I am trying to hide the navigation bar 'back' button during an animation.  When the animation completes, the button re-appears.

my code is as follows:

```
- (void) animateResults {

    [self hideNavBarButtons];

    [self animatePlayer1];
    [self animatePlayer2];

    [self performSelector:@selector(showNavBarButtons) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];


}


- (void) hideNavBarButtons {

    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];

}

- (void) showNavBarButtons {

    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];

}
```

This works fine on the simulator... but I get weird results on the device.  It is very inconsistent, and stops hiding the 'back' button after a few tries.  I am assuming I have some delegates messed up.. but I am lost.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any help out there?  I am stumped.

Comment: When you run on the device, when does the button come back?